# sbcl keep as much precision as possible when converting rational to decimal notation

Tags: format, common-lisp, sbcl

I have a simple lisp program here that computes an approximation of the average length between two points chosen uniformly at random on the unit interval. If I run the program, I get a rational number `16666671666667/50000000000000`, but when I (naively) try to format the rational number to 20 places, some of the precision is thrown away `0.33333343000000000000`. I think that, under the hood, SBCL is casting the rational to a floating point number before formatting it, but I'm not really sure how to tell. I'm just using the expression `(format t "~20$~%" (scale-all-line-contributions 10000000 1)`. Is there a way to convert a rational number to decimal notation keeping as much precision as possible? I understand the format system is powerful and expansive, but I'm having trouble finding documentation about it specifically related to rational numbers.

Here's the code below for completeness' sake, since it isn't very long.

```
(defun number-of-pairs (n i)
  "get the number of pairs with distance x
  for non-zero distances we have to consider two cases"
  (cond
    ((= i 0) n)
    ((> i 0) (* 2 (- n i)))
    ((> i n) 0)))

(defun line-contribution (n i power)
  "get the number of segments of length i in a line of n segments and their weight combined"
  (let
    ((number-of-pairs (number-of-pairs n i))
     (weight-of-pair (expt i power)))
    (* number-of-pairs weight-of-pair)))

(defun all-line-contributions (n power)
  "get the line contributions for reach [0 .. n]"
  (loop for i from 1 upto (- n 1) summing (line-contribution n i power)))

(defun normalized-all-line-contributions (n power)
  "normalize line contributions by number of pairs"
  (let ((pair-count (expt n 2)))
    (/ (all-line-contributions n power) pair-count)))

(defun scale-all-line-contributions (n power)
  "scale the line contributions by the distance n
  this will guarantee convergence"
  (/ (normalized-all-line-contributions n power) (expt n power)))

(print (scale-all-line-contributions 10000000 1))
(format t "~20$~%" (scale-all-line-contributions 10000000 1))
```

edit: fixed logic error in code. new rational number, float pair is `33333333333333/100000000000000 0.33333334000000000000`

Comment: You could use `(COERCE ... 'LONG-FLOAT)` to get a bit more precicion. I'm not sure why you want to though. If you're using the number for calculations, you should just keep it as a rational, or if it's just for humans to view, you might as well round it to 0.33.

Comment: FORMAT ~$ converts the rational to a single float. That's described in the ANSI CL standard (-> Hyperspec). As the answers explain, convert it to a float with more bits, first.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid the intermediate float and produce a decimal approximation with the given number of digits directly? I'm just using this a silly way of inspecting how quickly the limit of sums converges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use either [coerce](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_coerce.htm#coerce) or [float](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_float.htm). For instance:

```
(format t "~20$" (coerce 16666671666667/50000000000000 'long-float))

; prints 0.33333343333334000000

(format t "~a" (float 16666671666667/50000000000000 1.0l0))

; prints 0.33333343333334d0
```

Note that a coercion to `long-float` can produce different results in different implementations of Common Lisp (in particular in [CLISP](http://www.clisp.org)).

The second parameter to `float` is a prototype: you should provide any float literal and the first parameter will be converted to the same kind of [float](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_float.htm).